# How to obtained and use the type of variable?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a function process Mat, using OpenCV. My problem is that when the type of Input matrix changes, I need corresponding type of ptr.

For example:

1. for `CV_8UC1`, I need `ptr<uchar>`,
2. for `CV_16UC1` I need `ptr<UINT16>`,

However I cannot use `Mat.type()`, since it only returns an `int` for `enum`.

I thought of using switch-case, but it's rather verbose. Is there any concise way to do it?

Comment: Short answer: not really. The problem is that the data type inside the Mat isn't know at compile time, it is decided during runtime. You'll need something like a switch-case. In order to not having to write the same functions multiple times, templated functions are useful, so that the switch-case only becomes a thin layer that calls the templated function of the correct type.

Comment: find the optimal type for your task and convert the Mat to that type.